# Devolver un nodo según criterio de sus nodos padres y relaciones en 2 sentidos

Tags: relaciones, nodos, neo4j

tengo que resolver una query "compleja" en Cypher. Tal vez es algo simple para un entendido, pero yo soy un completo novato en el tema y busqué por varios lados pero no logré resolverlo por completo.

Con estas relaciones, y dada una lista de items que tengo, debo averiguar si podría adquirir otro item que necesito.
Algunos items habilitan el uso de nuevos items, y algunos items requieren tener mas de un item para poder ser utilizado.

[image: relaciones entre items]

Ejemplos (ver imagen):

- Si tengo el Item A, ¿podría usar el Item B? Sí.
- Si tengo el Item B, ¿podría usar el Item D? Sí.
- Si tengo el Item B, ¿podría usar el Item E? No, porque también necesito el Item C.
- Si tengo los Item A y B, ¿podría usar el Item E? No, porque también necesito el Item C.
- Si tengo los Item A, B y C, ¿podría usar el Item E? Sí.

Los datos iniciales son la lista de items que tengo (no es vacía), como ser: ['Item A', 'Item B']
y el item que necesito, como ser: 'Item D'

El valor de retorno podría ser un boleano, o directamente el nodo del item buscado.

EL grafo puede crearse con este script:

```
MERGE (n:Item {name: 'Item A' });
MERGE (n:Item {name: 'Item B' });
MERGE (n:Item {name: 'Item C' });
MERGE (n:Item {name: 'Item D' });
MERGE (n:Item {name: 'Item E' });

MATCH (it: Item { name: 'Item A' })
  MATCH (otherIt: Item { name: 'Item B' })
  MERGE (it)-[:Enables]->(otherIt);

MATCH (it: Item { name: 'Item A' })
  MATCH (otherIt: Item { name: 'Item C' })
  MERGE (it)-[:Enables]->(otherIt);

MATCH (it: Item { name: 'Item B' })
  MATCH (otherIt: Item { name: 'Item D' })
  MERGE (it)-[:Enables]->(otherIt);

MATCH (it: Item { name: 'Item B' })
  MATCH (otherIt: Item { name: 'Item E' })
  MERGE (it)-[:Enables]->(otherIt);

MATCH (it: Item { name: 'Item C' })
  MATCH (otherIt: Item { name: 'Item E' })
  MERGE (it)-[:Enables]->(otherIt);

MATCH (it: Item {name: 'Item B'})
 MATCH (req: Item {name: 'Item E'})
 MERGE (req)-[:Requires]->(it);

MATCH (it: Item {name: 'Item C'})
 MATCH (req: Item {name: 'Item E'})
 MERGE (req)-[:Requires]->(it);
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64940321/fetch-nodes-according-to-parents-and-two-way-relations, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Se Puede hacer una busqueda directa en el grafo y que el busque lo que ya se tiene.

```
MATCH (n:Item)
WHERE exists(n.name)
RETURN
  n.name AS name,
  exists((n {name: 'Item A' })-[:Enables]->(n2:Item {name: 'Item B'}) AS is_accesible_B,
  exists((n {name: 'Item B' })-[:Enables]->(n2:Item {name: 'Item C'})<-[:Enebles]-(n {name: 'Item A' }) ) AS is_accesible_C
```